# What's more efficient and compact: A huge set of linkedlist variables or a two-dimensional arraylist containing each of these?

Tags: java

I want to create a large matrix (n by n) where each element corresponds to a LinkedList (of certain objects).

I can either

1. Create the n*n individual linked lists and name them with the help of eval() within a loop that iterates through both dimensions (or something similar), so that in the end I'll have LinkedList_1_1, LinkedList_1_2 etc. Each one has a unique variable name. Basically, skipping the matrix altogether.
2. Create an ArrayList of ArrayLists and then push into each element a linked list.

Please recommend me a method if I want to conserve time & space, and ease-of-access in my later code, when I want to reference individual LinkedLists. Ease-of-acess will be poor with Method 1, as I'll have to use eval whenever I want to access a particular linked list.

My gut-feeling tells me Method 2 is the best approach, but how exactly do I form my initializations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know the sizes to start with, why don't you just use an array? Unfortunately Java generics prevents the array element itself from being a concrete generic type, but you can use a wildcard:

```
LinkedList<?>[][] lists = new LinkedList<?>[n][n];
```

Or *slightly* more efficient in memory, just a single array:

```
LinkedList<?>[] lists = new LinkedList<?>[n * n];

// Then for access...
lists[y * n + x] = ...;
```

Then you'd need to cast on each access - using `@SuppressWarnings` given that you know it will always work (assuming you encapsulate it appropriately). I'd put that in a single place:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private LinkedList<Foo> getList(int x, int y) {
    if (lists[y][x] == null) {
        lists[y][x] = new LinkedList<Foo>();
    }
    // Cast won't actually have any effect at execution time. It's
    // just to tell the compiler we know what we're doing.
    return (LinkedList<Foo>) lists[y][x];
}
```

Of course in both cases you'd then need to populate the arrays with empty linked lists *if* you needed to. (If several of the linked lists never end up having any nodes, you may wish to consider only populating them lazily.)

I would *certainly* not generate a class with hundreds of variables. It would make programmatic access to the lists very painful, and basically be a bad idea in any number of ways.

Comment: I didnt know you could use generic arrays for storing linkedlists, thanks

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn: Scratch this - it does indeed cause some issues. Editing.

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn: See the edit. It's slightly ugly, but does basically get the result you want.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I know in advance what kind of objects I will populate the n*n LinkedLists with. In this case, do I still need to use the wildcard type specifier <?>? I will use your first (2D) statement because it looks like it's simpler to work with.

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn: Yes, I believe you still need a wildcard - a simple test just using `List<String>[]` failed for me, but `List<?>[]` worked. Try to keep all the unchecked operations in as few places as you can.

Comment: Not sure yet if I also have to pass in the variable "lists" into this function as a third parameter if I call it from main (where "lists" was declared). If so, every get-invocation will need to transfer this huge matrix inside this function.

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn: It sounds like you need to revise a *lot* about how references work in Java before going any further. If you're new to Java, you should be concentrating on learning the basics of the language and getting something *working* before worrying about efficiency. Also, consider your OO design - why would you need to pass this around in `main` rather than making it a private field within a type?

Comment: "private field within a type" is this an enum obj at the level of the class or a constructor? I'm new to Java and I have googled that phrase but I couldn't figure out yet what it means. Thanks

Comment: Oh, I think I have to declare it outside main, within the class level.

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn: Why would it be an enum? It's just a field. I would take a step back from your current target, and learn Java from a book first - trying to apply it to a real problem as you learn is likely to leave you confused.